# I am trying to insert calendar in html but the format is changing as compared to rest of the tabs. Can anyone suggest what am I missing?

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to insert a calendar in html.

This is the code that I have used

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="suppliersince" required [(ngModel)]="model.suppliersince" name="suppliersince">
```

But the calendar tab is not in right format as compared to the rest of the tabs. Can anyone suggest what am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The content of calendar tab may have padding or margin assigned to it compared to the rest of the tabs. Inspect element to see if extra styles are applied.

Comment: I tried to do the inspect element. If I change the padding of that particular tab the whole column is changing. Is there anyway to make it a text box and then add up the calendar?

Comment: If you could provide an example or a plunker i could have a look for you.